# how to override the servers default 404 error message with react app

Tags: reactjs, apache, server, cpanel

I was hosting my react app on a shared server. And I found out there is a bit of disagreement about what to do with URL's between the apache server itself and my app. I will demonstrate what I mean.

so in my react app I have a route like this.

```
<Route path="/pages" exact render={(props) => (<Pages {...props} />)}/>
```

And this works perfectly as long as you are in the react app. So in the `'mydomain/'` `url` if you press a button that will link you to the `'/pages'` `url` a specific component is loaded because the react app knows what that is supposed to be. But if you directly go to search bar and type  "`mydomain/pages"` and press enter it isn't the react app that is going to decided what to do like it would in a server started with `npm start`, but the rather the apache server decides what to do, and because there is no physical (index.php/html or any) file in the `mydomain/pages` the server returns `404 error`. I totally understood what the problem is, but I couldn't think of a solution. What can I do to make the react app respond to url changes in that domain rather than the apaches server it self. Thanks!

If you want to check the website I was talking about here is a [link](https://hileamlak.com).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writing manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually)